# Power Query only load first 20 columns

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

My current code

```
let
Filepath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Filepath"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Subpath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="path_2.3"]}[Content]{0}[Column2],
Mappe = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="path_2.3"]}[Content]{0}[Column3],
Path = Folder.Files(Filepath&Subpath),
File = Path [Name]{0},
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(Filepath&Subpath&File), null, true),
Import = Source{[Item=Mappe,Kind="Sheet"]}[Data]
in
Import
```

Issue: The Sheet the code loads is messy and I can not change it (company stuff reasons).
The sheet contains millions of blank columns which inflates the resulting table into many MB big.

`Import = Source{[Item=Mappe,Kind="Sheet"]}[Data]` loads all data.

What I need: A code to dynamicly load only the first 20 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new step like this:

```
= Table.SelectColumns(Import, List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Import), 20))
```